# Qual a alternativa para a função showmodaldialog?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

No meu sistema as popups modais não funcionam mais no Chrome e nem no Firefox, após a atualização do componente JQuery. A aplicação é Webform e tem várias popups e é essencial que sejam modais. Qual a alternativa para o código abaixo?

```
   var ReturnValue = window.showModalDialog("/Popups/Cancelados/frmConPesPCanc1.aspx?doc=" + cgc + "&txAnos=" + slAnos, "", "dialogHeight: 600px; dialogWidth:1000px; dialogTop: 50px;  edge: Raised; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: Yes; status: No;");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está usando webforms, uma boa alternativa seria usar o modal do bootstrap, eles são elegantes e funcionam muito bem.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
 Launch demo modal
 </button>

 <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Referencia](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)